# how to ensure bash pipe processes do not overlap?

Tags: bash

How to ensure that in the bash pipe

```
bash>foo | bar
```

`bar` starts only after `foo` finishes?

Comment: Not a programming question but instead an OS question

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you are depending on output files from `foo` then don't use a pipe.

Comment: @KevinDTimm  I will disagree.  I am writing a bash script, this line is in the script.  Script programming is programming.

Comment: @EtanReisner it is because `foo` involves `ps` and I don't want `bar` to be inside the `ps` output

Comment: @MarkGaleck, if you're using `ps | grep`, don't do that at all; use `pgrep` instead, which is smart enough to exclude itself.

Comment: (although, really, most uses of `pgrep` can be replaced with a better alternative as well -- be that better alternative use of lockfiles, process-tree-based maintenance, or the like)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well no, it's not so simple, pgrep does not have all the functionality of ps and grep.  no, I really need both ps and grep.  OK I will output to temp file in the middle.

Comment: @MarkGaleck, care to explain what you're actually trying to accomplish? If this is "check to see if a process has exited to restart it", for instance, process-tree-aware supervision systems are the Right Thing. If this is "make sure another process has finished", advisory locking is the Right Thing (and trying to use `ps` for the job actually creates race-condition bugs). Using the right tool for the job is important, and if you don't tell us what the job is...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  I hate when they say that :)  I am trying to make an SSCCE as proper, and they want instead to solve my problem.  OK.  I need to kill processes based on some grepping, and the problem is, the grepping tends to yield the calling process itself as well as the grep inside the pipe.  It's OK, temporary file will do it.

Comment: A SSCCE is fine to help you find a bug in X, but if X is an inherently error-prone way to do Y... well, then, asking "what's the best way to do Y?" would be the thing most beneficial to building a robust implementation. But, anyhow, yes -- we have an answer for the immediate question here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how pipes work. `foo | bar` **always** runs both `foo` and `bar` at the same time, because it's connecting `foo`'s output to `bar`'s input with a minimal buffer if any.

If you want to run them separately, don't use a pipeline; rather, write output to a file:

```
foo >out
bar <out
```

...you also have the option of using a variable to store output in memory:

```
out=$(foo)
bar <<<"$out"
```

...though this isn't byte-for-byte accurate (discards trailing newlines, for instance).

Comment: Thank you Charles.  My question was basically, can one avoid running them at the same time, but instead, order them.  I guess your answer is, no, there is no such option.

Answer (score 1):

The pipe serves to connect the output of foo to the input of bar. If foo is finished, bar cannot get any input.

Maybe what you want is simply

```
foo ; bar
```

If bar needs to consume output of `foo`, then an intermediate file is one solution. Another, if the argument to `grep` are hardcoded, is to use the brackets

```
ps aux | grep [p]attern
```

Another solution is to install and use the `[buffer][1]` command

```
foo | buffer -m ... | bar
```

with `-m ...` the size of the buffer large enough to hold the output of the `foo` command.

Answer (score 1):

The way the pipe works, `foo` and `bar` run in two separate subshells. Thereby, as soon as output is made available by `foo`, `bar` is able to consume it (by reading its `stdin`--because pipes-based IPC, the communication between the processes running on two separate subshells is entirely using the FIFO queue used to send `stdout` from `foo` into `bar`'s `stdin`. Thereby, `bar` in this context doesn't know, or care, about whether or not `foo` ended. It only cares about what is placed on its `stdin`.

You have to use another type of invocation for `foo` and `bar` if you care about `foo`'s completion.

Comment: Looks like Charles beat me to the punch. Also, his redirection based method is one way to achieve what I think you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a pipe as they would always run simultaneously. The proper way to make that mechanism work is to use a buffer:

```
buffer=$(foo)
echo "$buffer" | bar
```

Or

```
bar <<EOF
$(foo)
EOF
```

- `echo -n` doesn't really make it strict as `$()` trims out `0x0A` at the end.